# ElseOr or AndAlso in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Good afternoon,

I'm new to Visual Basic (and Stack Overflow) and I have a fairly simple question about the distinction between `ElseOr` and `AndAlso`.

If I'm building an `If...Then...Else` statement that involved identifying days of the week (i.e. Weekend as Saturday and Sunday) would I want to say `If(text input) = 'Saturday' AndAlso Sunday = 'weekend'`, or would I want to say `If Saturday OrElse Sunday = x Then weekend`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be `OrElse`. And watch the spacing... the keywords are `AndAlso` and `OrElse`. It won't work with the spaces between those words.

```
Dim day As String  = Console.ReadLine()
Dim weekend AS Boolean = False
If day = "Saturday" OrElse day = "Sunday" Then weekened = True
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.